# Sub-query returned more than 1 value: executing UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, stored-procedures

I'm using AdventureWorks 2007 for this sample, trying to enter the employee birthdate and return their age

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_EmpAge  (@BusinessEntityID  VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Emp_Age VARCHAR(50)
    SET @Emp_Age = (SELECT  DATEDIFF(YY,[BirthDate],GETDATE()) FROM HumanResources.Employee)
    RETURN  
    (
        SELECT @Emp_Age 
        FROM HumanResources.Employee 
        WHERE BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID
    )
END
GO
```

when I try to run it for example

```
SELECT  dbo.UDF_EmpAge(2)
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 50
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>  follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: This line `SET @Emp_Age = (SELECT  DATEDIFF(YY,[BirthDate],GETDATE()) FROM HumanResources.Employee)` - the error is because there is more than one record in the table and you haven't specified which one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query returns multiple rows, so you cannot assign that to a scalar variable.

I don't see the point for that intermediate query anyway. You can directly filter the table using the parameter, and assign the result of the date function to the variable (which should be an integer rather than a string).

Consider:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_EmpAge(@BusinessEntityID VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Emp_Age INT;

    SELECT @Emp_Age = DATEDIFF(YY, [BirthDate] ,GETDATE()) 
    FROM HumanResources.Employee
    WHERE BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID;

    RETURN @Emp_Age;
END
```

Note that this assumes that `BusinessEntityID` is a unique key in `HumanResources.Employee` table (or its primary key).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any variables at all.  You can just return the result of the query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_EmpAge (@BusinessEntityID  VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, BirthDate, GETDATE()) 
           FROM Employee 
           WHERE BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID
          );
END;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7947be0fdd6d234be69790892d0731fb) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that "age" is more properly thought of as a number; and `datediff()` returns an integer.  It doesn't make sense to return this value as a string.